# how to solv UnicodeEncodeError using tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

When i run this code i get an error

i used on other code i wrote 'encoding ('utf-8)' , but i cant figure out how to use it in this code.

thank you for your time.

```
import tweepy
from api_keys import *



auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = (api.verify_credentials())

print (user)

"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character.." # <---the error
```

Comment: Hi @jojo_hal and welcome to SO! Can you post the full error message so we can better assist you?